# JMeter after load XML files from a directory how to pass variables to the each XML body?

Tags: jmeter

let say I have multiple XLMs files in folder and use jp@gc  Directory Listing upload the files. so how do I pass variables to body xmls?

```
 <Address>

          <Address1>${address}</Address1>

          <City>${city}</City>

          <State>${state}</State>

          <ZipOrPostalCode>${zip}</ZipOrPostalCode>

          <Country>USA</Country>

        </Address>
```

I tried to use jsr223- preprocessor but not success

Answer (score 0):

Use [__FileToString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__FileToString) and [__eval()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__eval) functions combination like:

```
${__eval(${__FileToString(${filename},,)})}
```

[image]

where `filename` is the variable from the Directory Listing Config

See [Apache JMeter Functions - An Introduction](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-functions) article for more information on JMeter Functions concept

Comment: vars.put(${address},"123 test street");

Comment: You can go for [User Defined Variables](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421395-Using-User-Defined-Variables) to declare initial set of [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) for using later on